# Getting the class for Main in Scala

Tags: class, scala, program-entry-point

If I create a singleton object `Main` with no companion class, is there any way to get the class of that singleton? `classOf[Main]` gives an error: "not found: type Main".

Comment: In case you want to use that in order to start a program with a main method which is part of a companion object for a class with the same name - it won't work. Scala only has the special handling of the main method for objects that are not companions, for whatever reason.

Comment: @Madoc: I thought that was fixed in 2.8.0. In any case, I still create a `Main` object with no companion. It usually just contains the `main` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's an instance of a class, you can use the method `Main.getClass` to pull this one off.

Behind the scenes, the JVM knows that `Main` is an instance of a class named `Main$`, and this can be accessed via Java reflection methods if necessary.

Having said all of that, there's usually very little need for reflection in Scala anyway, so you shouldn't really need this unless you're just after an interesting bit of theory.

Comment: Use case: `val buildNumber = try { new Manifest(new URL("jar:" + classOf[Main].getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation + "!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF").openStream).getMainAttributes.getValue("Build-Number") } catch { case _: ZipException => "0" }`

Answer (score 0):

Singleton objects, aka modules, do not have a "class" as you cannot inherit from them. Think of singleton and class as opposite notions.

They do have a type though:

```
object Main

def test(a: Main.type): Unit = println("Got: " + a)

test(Main)
```

Comment: What's the difference between "class" and "type" here?

Comment: Well, as I said, a module is not a class in that you can inherit from it. So Main is rather a value ("instance") than a class. Main.type gives you the "singleton-type" of a value. See http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch12.html (paragraph Singleton Types), also http://blogs.sun.com/sundararajan/entry/mis_understaning_scala_s_singleton